# Doesn't "find" exist on any kind of typescript or javascript array?

Tags: typescript

Notice the error message at the bottom: "config.ts(19,28): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Answer[]". I thought all arrays would have a "find" method.

I am sure I am missing something!

[image]

Comment: Array.prototype.find() is part of ES6. Link => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Aha! And using typescript doesn't give me bridge to that particular es6 feature. What's the closest useful es5 feature?

Comment: kkaosninja's link includes a polyfill.

Comment: Never heard that term 'polyfill'. I assume its standard js term of art. Where would i put that bit of code within my codebase so that it does the right thing?

Comment: Anywhere, as long as it gets run before you try to use it.

Answer (score 30):

Since Typescript 2.0 you could also use the `--lib` compiler flag or a `"lib": []` section in your `tsconfig.js` file to include `ES6` features, while still targeting `ES5`. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6974

In this case just include the following configuration options in your `tsconfig.js`:

```
...
"lib": [ "es6" ],
"target": "es5"
...
```

Answer (score 10):

To answer your question it exists in TypeScript but not without some configurations.
To fix the issue you need to update your `compilerOptions` as follows:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "target": "es5"
 }
```

> **TypeScript 2.0**

Answer (score 7):

Just a wrap up of all other answers. Create a `tsconfig.json` in you project root directory, and make sure you have this in you config:

```
{
  ... (other configs)
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ],
    "target": "es5"
  }
  ... (other configs)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As said before, the `find` function is indeed part of ES6.

We fixed it by using `filter` instead and taking the first element of the resulting array.

Answer (score 4):

with "lib": ["es6"]  I am getting more errors, less with  [ "es2017", "dom" ]:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "es6",
        "lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ]
        ...............
  }
```

And it solves the problem with [].find()

Answer (score 2):

So... If you use Typescript then you could be using Array.prototype.find() because Typescript is a superset of javascript. **BUT** because you 'compile' to ES5 you get the error, because the method *find* is part of ES6 (ES2015), but not ES5.

It took me a while to realize of this obvious fact. It is not your typescript, it is to what you target.

Comment: I tried all the other answers, but only changing the target to ES6 worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue from a node application. where I start files from scratch.
What I did to solve the issue is to install the "@types/node" package to my project.
To install the package I used the following command

npm install @types/node --save-dev

This solution might be helpful for those who started to learn Typescript from the beginning.

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer was included in the comment by kkaosninja: find is part of es6 and I am still on es5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

You can just force assertion by wrapping the value like this:

```
(value) as type[]
```

I rather do this and change the entire configuration of typescript to avoid get more errors.